# Why comparing numbers with min() and max() is slower than conditional statement

Tags: php

I had to optimize code which ran slowly with large dataset which was looking good. After testing and logging execution times I found loop with few max() comparisons of two integers. Then after quick peek in the documentation I saw the following comment:
"I had several occasions that using max is a lot slower then using a if/then/else construct. Be sure to check this in your routines!"

So I replace it with ternary operator and the execution time was around 2/3 faster.

Then I became curious why max() is working so much slower than a simple statement and what is behind this functions. But I couldn't find any explanation so far.

Also in the past I come across similar problems with array_search() which is working much slower than foreach with statement.

I ran the test on PHP 7.1.

```php
$firstLoop = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    $testOne = max($i, 1000000);
}

error_log(microtime(true) - $firstLoop); 

$secondLoop = microtime(true); // 1.3123650550842

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    $testTwo = $i > 1000000 ? $i : 1000000; 
}

error_log(microtime(true) - $secondLoop); // 0.090374946594238
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`max` is a complete function call and allows an arbitrary list of arguments. This has a lot of overhead compared to a simple comparison which can be performed inline without setting up a complete function call context. In your example you're doing a million function calls, and this adds up in total.

Two different methods (that support (and can do) different things) isn't necessary implemented in the same way even if they give the same result as in your example.

You can see this from the opcodes generated by the VM, the first call generates the following statements:

```
   6     6    >   INIT_FCALL                                               'max'
         7        SEND_VAR                                                 !1
         8        SEND_VAL                                                 1000000
         9        DO_ICALL                                         $8      
        10        ASSIGN                                                   !2, $8
   5    11        POST_INC                                         ~10     !1
        12        FREE                                                     ~10
        13    >   IS_SMALLER                                       ~11     !1, 1000000
```

While the second case generates just JMP calls:

```
        27      > JMP                                                      ->36
  14    28    >   IS_SMALLER                                       ~18     1000000, !1
        29      > JMPZ                                                     ~18, ->32
        30    >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~19     !1
        31      > JMP                                                      ->33
        32    >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~19     1000000
        33    >   ASSIGN                                                   !4, ~19
  13    34        POST_INC                                         ~21     !1
        35        FREE                                                     ~21
        36    >   IS_SMALLER                                       ~22     !1, 1000000
```

`JMP` calls doesn't have to set up the whole function call structure, and thus can be executed a lot faster.

It's also worth nothing that the [difference in general seems to be about 1/2 the time](https://3v4l.org/BqhVl#output) for the simple comparison on the current versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are taking multiple times and then averaging them out and then deciding which code is running faster.
On my machine the code using max function took on average (10 results) **0.08** and the if statement taking **0.044** 
We can see the if condition is taking almost half the time than min function. This time difference make sense if we account for what happens when a function is called.

1) Arguments to the function are stored on the stack. In platform specific order.

2) Location for return value is "allocated" on the stack

3) The return address for the function is also stored in the stack or in a special purpose CPU register.

4) The function (or actually, the address of the function) is called, either through a CPU specific call instruction or through a normal jmp or br instruction (jump/branch)

5) The function reads the arguments (if any) from the stack and the runs the function code

6) Return value from function is stored in the specified location (stack or special purpose CPU register)

7) Execution jumps back to the caller and the stack is cleared (by restoring the stack pointer to its initial value).

Visit [What happens in assembly language when you call a method/function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585137/what-happens-in-assembly-language-when-you-call-a-method-function)

If we account for all this details and the increased line of code inside the function to handle multiple conditions to search for max then the time difference makes sense.

Visit https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php to check out the conditions the function handles that increase the line of code and thus increasing the execution time.
The similar response to array_search and min function.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous PHP versions, it was much slower than this. they are improving the speed of each library functions like max() & min() function in new versions.

as MatsLindh said in library functions like max() and min() they have a lot of overheads which will not be needed by us in a simple comparison like you did in the second part.

if you read the [PHP manual max()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) it says...

> if the first and only parameter is an array, max() returns the highest
>   value in that array. If at least two parameters are provided, max()
>   returns the biggest of these values.

so it first checks that it is an array or not which will take some execution time. in your case, you are just comparing value and not checking for an array.

> Values of different types will be compared using the standard
>   comparison rules. For instance, a non-numeric string will be compared
>   to an integer as though it were 0, but multiple non-numeric strings
>   values will be compared alphanumerically. The actual value returned
>   will be of the original type with no conversion applied.

so there are more functions inside a max function which will take some time to execute.

Apart from that function takes more time than a simple comparison. that is why functional-based programming languages like Lisp are slower than a decent hash table.

They require infrastructure that inevitably adds overheads over what can theoretically be attained using assembler by hand. In particular, first-class lexical closures only work well with garbage collection because they allow values to be carried out of scope.

probably the single biggest bottleneck in functional languages today: their excessive allocation rates.